# Path and Entry Template problems when developing locally

Tags: templating

I feel this a simple problem to fix, but I can't find an answer anywhere.

I am developing locally on using MAMP.

Everything on my site is working great until I call up page using a template inside a folder inside the templates directory. At that point the paths are broken to any and all assets (CSS, images, etc.)

For example, if I set the Entry Template for a section in Craft to say news/_entry and then view a news article page... I get an un-styled page.

I am including the CSS like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/assets/css/nav.css">
```

and the images like:

```html
<img src="../public/assets/images/swf_logo.png" alt="" />
```

Comment: Can you share how you are including your css as well as how you are setting the src in your img tags?

Comment: Could you post the code for your layout template and the _entry template?

Comment: Yes Natetronn...

in my _layouts.html I am including the CSS like
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/assets/css/nav.css">

and the images like
<img src="../public/assets/images/swf_logo.png" alt="" />

Comment: @alec-ritson here is my _entry template code...

{% extends "_layout" %}

{% block content %}
 <article class="newsarticles">
  <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
  <p class="newsdate">Posted on {{ entry.postDate.format('F d, Y') }}</p>
  {{ entry.body }}
 </article>
{% endblock %}

Comment: @JamesLedford Can you edit your original question with the template code?  Difficult to read code in comments.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I installed craft in sub folder of live site for testing.
It is xzy.com/munkak/craft-/
I can put in my _layout.html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/munkak/craft-/css/html5reset.css" media="all">
that is working fine.
But targeting the images directory does not work the same way from calling from a css file like so: background: url("/munkak/craft-/assets/images/logo.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
this css is in /munkak/craft-/craft/templates/css An absolute src from xzy.com/munkak/craft-/assets/images/logo.jpg works.
I am stuck with this.
Any help would be gre

Comment: @CsabaDobo: I'd recommend [asking a new question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), since this thread is already long and complicated. Feel free to reference back to this thread, so people know you're dealing with a similar problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your image/CSS/JS URLs should be either absolute, protocol-relative, or root-relative:

```html
<!-- absolute -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/assets/css/nav.css">
<img src="http://example.com/assets/images/swf_logo.png" alt="" />

<!-- protocol-relative -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//example.com/assets/css/nav.css">
<img src="//example.com/assets/images/swf_logo.png" alt="" />

<!-- root-relative -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/nav.css">
<img src="/assets/images/swf_logo.png" alt="" />
```

Relative URLs (which start with either `./`, `../`, or no slash at all) are generally a bad idea, since the URL will need to vary depending on the number of segments in your URI.

For example if you were to access http://example.com/, the relative path to your nav.css would be `assets/css/nav.css`, but if you were to access http://example.com/about/ (with a trailing slash), then the proper relative URL would be `../assets/css/nav.css`.

That’s not to say that relative URLs are impossible. The main issue with your URLs is not that they’re relative, it’s that you’re treating them as relative from the *physical template file location*. Keep in mind that these front-end resource URLs are resolved by the *browser*, not by the server, and browsers have no idea how the resulting HTML gets generated, let alone that it came from a template that happened to live a couple directories up from your web root, and in a craft/templates/... subfolder. So they need to be relative based an the *apparent* location of the webpage, as defined by its URI (e.g. “/news/some-slug”).

Comment: The difference between Brandon's answer and mine is that I'm just telling you how to get the job done. He on the other hand is trying to educate you. I give you examples of both absolute (via Craft Tags & Vars) as well as root-relative paths though, I didn't explain the why; just the how. Point being is that you should consider reading Brandon's answer before you read mine :-)

Comment: Thanks so much guys! I knew I was letting the paths get away from me somehow. Brandon did clear this up by his education. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [includeCssFile Tag](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/includecssfile) for your CSS files (there is another for [js files](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/includejsfile) for what ever it's worth)

So for example in your case you'd have:

`{% includeCssFile "/assets/css/nav.css" %}`

Note: I think that is correct though you might need to play with the path a bit. Specifically the first slash.

For the img tags you can probably get way with this:

`<img src="/assets/images/swf_logo.png" alt="" />`

or if you want you could add the [siteUrl Global Variable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/global-variables#siteUrl) to the mix as well

`<img src="{{ siteUrl }}assets/images/swf_logo.png" alt="" />`

Note: again you might need to play with the starting slash depending on your config setup and siteUrl ending with a slash or not:

`{{ siteUrl }}/assets/images/swf_logo.png`